# Explain the equation when calculating the probability that two numbers selected at random are relatively prime

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

I am following this book - [Excursions in Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486257789). In chapter 3, page 29, a question posed to the reader is *What is the probability that two numbers selected at random are relatively prime?* The author goes on to say that we can solve the problem for the first few numbers like 1 to 100 and then do it over the numbers 1 to 1000 and so on. Then, the author introduces basic ideas and principles of probability and states that the probability of *n* independent events is the product of their separate probabilities. So far, so good! The very next line, he mentions that ...

*The biggest gun in our arsenal is this rather astonishing equation:*

$ (1+ \frac {1}{2^2} + \frac {1}{3^2}+ \frac {1}{4^2}+ \frac {1}{5^2}+ ...) (1-\frac {1}{2^2})(1- \frac {1}{3^2}) (1- \frac {1}{5^2}) (1- \frac {1}{7^2}) (1- \frac {1}{11^2})... = 1 $

My question is what is this equation? Any idea how the author gets to this?

Comment: This is the Euler Product for the zeta function.  A good reference can be found, e.g., here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function